# Problem upploading videos and photos to instagram with instapy-cli

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram

Hi I have tried to upload to instagram with instapy-cli but I get this error `OSError: Unable to upload.` 
I don't know whats wrong or if it's posible to do this.

Here is the code i "wrote"

```
from instapy_cli import client

username = '******'
password = '*****'


video = 'pic.jpg'
text = 'Test'

with client(username, password) as cli:
    cli.upload(video, text)
```

So I guess the question is if it's still possible to post to instagram with python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error probably because Instagram made changes in the API.

I tried [Instagram-API-python](https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python) but upload is not working in it too.

There is official [Instagram Graph API endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/#publish-photos) for posting media but it is in closed beta with Facebook Marketing Partners and Instagram Partners only.

Only option left is [automating it with Selenium](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/1373#issuecomment-385097989).